# When creating a custom View in Swift, how can you draw on top of the current context from outside the drawRect function?

Tags: xcode, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to create bullet points that can be filled in with a:

```
fillCircle
```

function, but I found out that the only way to successfully do this is to pass the context from the drawRect function.

My class is set up so that first it draws the empty bullets with the drawRect function, as seen here:

```
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt)

    bulletColor.set()

    for i in 1...numberOfBullets{
      CGContextAddArc(context, CGFloat(Float(i) * Float(bulletSpacing)), self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 0)
      CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke)
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to implement a fillCircle function like so:

```
 func fillCircle(context: CGContextRef, circleNumber: Int){
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRect(x: CGFloat(circleNumber) * (bulletSpacing) - radius, y: self.frame.size.height/2 - radius, width: 2*radius, height: 2*radius))
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke)
  }
```

So that any users of the class can fill in bullets at will, but I can't seem to get the context from outside of drawrect. I can't pass in the context from drawRect because then it would be called every time the class is created.

How can i implement a fillCircle method without altering drawRect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you redraw it when a new bullet point is added? You can use `setNeedsDisplay` function for that.  Store a new variable indicating the number of lines with filled bullet point, numberOfFilledBullets.

`setNeedsDisplay` redraws the view and calls `drawRect` again.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt)

    bulletColor.set()

    for i in 1...numberOfBullets{
      CGContextAddArc(context, CGFloat(Float(i) * Float(bulletSpacing)), self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 0)
      CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke)

    }

    for i in 1...numberOfFilledBullets {
       // fillCircle
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * (bulletSpacing) - radius, y: self.frame.size.height/2 - radius, width: 2*radius, height: 2*radius))
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke)
    }
}

func addNewLine {
    numberOfFilledBullets ++
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

func deleteLine {
    numberOfFilledBullets --
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: That's right. You (the OP) need to rethink this. You do not need a `fillCircle` at all. Your `drawRect` should draw correctly for whatever the "state" of circles is. Then, every time the state changes, other objects can just tell the view to redraw. Another way of looking at this is - do not use the view to store state. Other objects set the state ("what circles should be filled and what circles should be empty") and then just tell the view to redraw - the view merely _portrays_ the current state.